# better understanding middleware protection in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

I wrote a very simple middleware, like this:

```php
class CheckToken
{

    private $token='xxx';
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {


        if (! $request->tokenz == $this->token) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then I register it trough kernel.php, like this:

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
       .....
        'CheckToken' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckToken::class,

    ];
```

then Ive a very simple function in a controller guarded by this controller:

```php
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('CheckToken');
    }


    public function push()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
```

Now starts what is not clear to me:

- **how can i "protect" my page using this simple method?**

I've tried to put this tag on the header of page but it seems to not works, maybe im in the wrong path:

```HTML
<meta name="tokenz" content="xxx">
```

I put it even in the body but no results.

what ive misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the middleware call to the actual route:

```php
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckAge;

Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware(CheckAge::class);
```

This was extracted from the Laravel 5.7 documentation: [Middleware - Assigning Middleware to Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes)

Comment: as you can see i put it in the constructor of the controller class, the problem is not add the middleware, it works! the problem is to understand how to passing the value to the middle were via get request

Answer (score 0):

sorry i can't create a comment. but just want to help.

does `$request` passed a `tokenz`?
you can use `?tokenz=blablabla`
or you can change your method to get the `tokenz`

Comment: no the problem is that one! howto add token to the head request!

Comment: try this `$request->headers->set('tokenz', 'xxxxx');`

Comment: still not understanding it...how can i protect a page via this method that u suggest me...